# Can we send commands to Alexa through Alexa app?

Tags: alexa

Let's say I'm not at home but I need to check whether my smart bulb at home is on or off? I know I can do it with the app that support my smart bulb but then I need to check each every app that I downloaded for each and every smart device I have.

Can we give remote commands to Alexa through Alexa app to check the status of my bulb, if it's turned on can I turned it off via a command send through Alexa app?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/253621/how-to-control-your-amazon-echo-from-anywhere/), it is possible.

> Amazon’s own shopping app on iOS now allows you to give your
> Amazon Echo voice commands through your phone, effectively getting rid
> of the need for the $30 Voice Remote, too. It doesn’t directly control
> your physical Amazon Echo unit, per se, but it acts as a virtual Echo
> device, communicating with your Alexa account and letting you control
> your smarthome devices by voice using Alexa on your phone.
>
> The feature uses the existing microphone button in the app that’s used
> for voice search. You can still use it for that, of course, but now
> Alexa is completely built in.

For Android:

> Unfortunately, this feature is not yet available in the Android
> version of the Amazon app, but luckily there’s a third-party app
> (called [Ubi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avsintegration.android)) that gives you similar functionality.

From the Play Store:

> Requirements
>
> This app requires that you have a valid Amazon account for sign in and
> for accessing the Alexa Voice Service.
>
> Supported features in this app:
>
> Asking Alexa questions and getting a response
>
> Controlling home automation devices
>
> Accessing various Alexa Skills
>
> Timers
>
> Alarms
>
> Etc.

Comment: Isn't that the Amazon shopping app that article is showing? Couldn't try Ubi though

Comment: Yes, it is. According to the article, you get pretty much full control over your Alexa device.